# Carrying out a jquery command based on conditional css style?

Tags: jquery, css, conditional-statements

I want to carry out two different functions based on the height of a div. How would I write out a conditional that checks the style before deciding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have:

```
var e = $("someSelectorThatGetsTheElement");
if (e.height() < 50) {
    // do something;
} else {
    // do something else;
}
```

EDIT: I made a small mistake, e.height is actually a function, so need to add the "()".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [height](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS)() method. The css(name) method can be used to return any style property.